# Prevent editing/formatting of word template when used as doc

Tags: microsoft-word

I created a word template; however, when I use it (create new doc and select the word template) it allows the user to modify the template.  In particular I have a picture that is the background and the user can move it around; often this is inadvertent as the user is just trying to click to type text.

How can a freeze the template so when used it can't be modified?  I do similar things in visio by assigning the items to a layer and freezing that layer.  That is the type of functionality I want.

I am using word 2016

Answer (score 0):

To make it harder for users to inadvertently move things like background images, have the header (or footer) open when you insert the image. Don't insert it in the document body. Then right-click the image, click **Size and Position**, and on the **Text Wrapping** tab, select **Behind text**.